# The pagaes in react js site shows 404 expect home page

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have a react site . My home page is displaying properly and the link from home page to other page is also working. 
I can go to my contact page from by home page by clicking contact us menu in the home page.
When i took the contact us page link directly it shows 404. not only contact us page all other pages too.
Is this with htaccess issue.
i have write a .htaccess file .
my root folder structure is like

```
[edu2mfgitulstagi@st03 edu2mfg-clean-architecture]$ ls
lerna.json  node_modules  package.json  packages  yarn.lock .htaccess

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
 </IfModule>
```

please help, iam new in react js

Comment: Have you imported htaccess in your index.js file??

Comment: lerna.json node_modules package.json packages yarn.lock .htaccess these are the files and folders in my root folder. from where i can found index.js file?